# RabbitMQ SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, rabbitmq

I'm trying to connect to RabbitMQ in Java with InteliJ IDEA (Maven 3.3.9), but an error occurs when doing the required step (creating `ConnectionFactory` object before connecting to RabbitMQ).

For detailed information: Maven itself installs `amqp-client:5.7.2` and `org.slf4j-api:1.7.26`.

What am I missing here? I tried to import `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`, but Java itself doesn't know this one.

```
package TestPackage;

import Configuration.RabbitMQConf;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class TestingClass {
    static ConnectionFactory rbmqFactory;
    static Connection rbmqConn;
    static Channel rbmqChannel;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        RabbitMQConf rbmqConf = new RabbitMQConf();


        rbmqFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        rbmqFactory.setUsername(rbmqConf.username);
        rbmqFactory.setPassword(rbmqConf.password);
        rbmqFactory.setVirtualHost(rbmqConf.virtualHost);
        rbmqFactory.setHost(rbmqConf.host);
        rbmqFactory.setPort(rbmqConf.port);
    }
}
```

I tried to run this and got this error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

here's my pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>XXXX</groupId>
  <artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-XXXX</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
      <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: which version of slf4j did you add to pom file?

Comment: i'm updating the thread, here is my pom.xml file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [link in the error](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) pretty much explains what's the problem and how to fix it. You just need to add one of the logging implementations to the dependencies in `pom.xml`.

> This warning message is reported when the
>   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into
>   memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found
>   on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar
>   slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or
>   logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```