# Intellij error while running Jar -> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, slf4j, jedis

I am using Intellij 2021.1.2 Community Edition with Java 16 and Maven 3.6.3 (bundled with Intellj) on Windows.

When I try to run my jar, here is the full error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have found a lot of questions regarding this error but none matching my specifics, so if this is a repeat, please point me to the correct solution.

My project was running great yesterday, and I haven't made any changes in any dependencies since yesterday so I am kind of confused as to what the issue could be. That said, I am trying to run a jar that uses the dependency Jedis. I have listed it in my pom as:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And it seems that slf4j is a dependency of Jedis, as I can see in the maven window here:

[image]

In Intellij, if I go to Project Structure -> Modules, slf4j is set to compile. If I go to the slf4j sources jar via the library filepath (C:\Users\MyUsername.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30-sources.jar) given in Project Structure -> Libraries and open the jar, I can see that the class file "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" does indeed exist. The dependency is only used for Jedis also, so there doesn't seem to be a dependency conflict or anything.

In maven I build the jar using the "Build Artifact" feature, compiling the libraries into a single jar. Compiling them as separate jars gives the same error.

What gives? Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/57118379/104891 helps. You don't have any logging implementation dependency present, only API.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue. To fix this issue, I changed the scope of slf4j dependency to "Test" from Compile and by going to File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies tab in IntelliJ. It fixed the problem

Comment: This method did not work as Jedis was not able to find its dependency. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory at redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort.<clinit>(HostAndPort.java:12)`