# IntelliJ, Grails user interface error message SLF4J: Failed to load

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails, groovy

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate, grails 222.3345.118 and jdk1.8.0_202. I am trying to build a simple user interface but I keep getting this error message.

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

pls help

Comment: Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/57118379/12844632 helps

Comment: I am using groovy, not Maven. I do not have the pom.xml file

Comment: Then you need to use whatever build tool you're using (I guess Gradle) to add a suitable dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the error just by changing the grails version, now I am using
https://grails.org/download.html version 4.1.1